# Garbage disposal will not shut off!

Tags: electrical, wiring

I recently replaced my garbage disposal. I had to unhook the wiring. Once I finished, I put the wiring back as it was, but as soon as went to the breaker box to flip the switch the garbage disposal came on. I had not even flip the switch in my kitchen to turn on the garbage disposal. Now it stays on, and I can’t turn it off or on with switch that is in the kitchen! HELP! Sorry couldn’t  upload a picture.

Comment: Is it plugged into a duplex wall outlet? If so, then move the plug to the outlet's other receptacle.

Comment: Pictures of wiring in any box you worked in would help.

Comment: When you edit your answer, click on the icon with two mountains, to add a picture.

Comment: What kind of switch do you have connected to your disposal?

Comment: First step to correcting it is to discard the false belief that you put it back as it was...

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the box with power for disposal also has a constant hot for the dish washer.  Either you accidentally connected to that wire, or you accidentally bypassed the switch. I think you have switch loop from disposal box to the switch, most likely using a 12-2 wire. You probably bypassed that loop and connected it directly to the incoming power.  Really will need a picture to help you get it back right.

Comment: Thanks Keith! I put in a new switch. Everything is working fine!